# How To Hide The Outline of The Polygon in Altium

Tags: altium, copper, polygon, pour

I have copied a polygon pour from one PCB to another, but I cannot seem to hide the outline on the new board. Anyone know how to do this? Comparison below:

New Board:

[image: NG]

Previous:

[image: OK]

Comment: Have you tried repouring the polygon?

Comment: Yes.. The Polygon is exactly the shape I need actually, it's that there's an outline which is making it hard to view the board as a whole from the overlapping lines.

Comment: Change the viewing style from "draft" to "hidden".

Comment: @ThePhoton Tried that too, but it hides the whole pour not just the outline :(

Comment: Sorry, then I don't get what you're trying to accomplish. What in your images are you calling "the pour" and what are you calling "the outline"?

Comment: Fair enough. I edited the image to help clarify what I mean by the outline! Yellow arrow is the **outline**, the **pour** is in red. Again I have no issue with the pour itself, I'm just wanting to remove the boarder outline around it.

Comment: So you're making a big polygon, and then using a keepout line within the polygon to define the actual shape you want filled?

Comment: There is a tool (that I haven't used before, but just now briefly tested) called "Create polygon from free primitives". You can (probably) use this to make a polygon the circular shape you want, rather than mess around with keepouts.

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry should have clarified.

Comment: I just did *Polygon Action --> Explode Selected Polygon to Free Primitives*. This removed the outline @ThePhoton, thanks!!

Comment: @Kiwi-Dan, that will work short term but it will be a mess if you move things around and create a violation that could otherwise be solved with a re-pour.

Comment: If you absolutely don't ever want to change the polygon shape, then I guess that's  a feature rather than a bug.

Comment: Understood, in this particular application if I need to re-pour I can re-copy from the previous file and repair from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're making a big polygon, and then using a keepout line within the polygon to define the actual shape you want filled.

Instead of doing that, you can use the function "create polygon from free primitives" to make the polygon the actual circular shape you want. (i.e. draw a circle, convert this to a polygon, change the polygon properties as desired) Then the outlines of the polygon will be on the edges of the filled area, and won't distract from viewing the rest of the design.